# What is tar error message " Cannot open: Invalid argument"

Tags: tar, filenames, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I download xcrysden source package from here http://www.xcrysden.org/download/xcrysden-1.5.60.tar.gz

Then I extract it using

```
tar zxvf xcrysden-1.5.60.tar.gz
```

However, I got several errors, as `tar zxvf xcrysden-1.5.60.tar.gz|grep tar:` shows

```
tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/examples/XSF_Files/c2h4\:Ag001.xsf: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/TclTk\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/Togl\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/Mesa\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/Meschach\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/LGPL\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/GL2PS\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/FFTW3\:LICENCE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: xcrysden-1.5.60/otherLICENSES/BWidget\:LICENSE: Cannot open: Invalid argument
    tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What does these message mean? Why does the extracting not complete?

Comment: Extracts fine for me. Maybe the download got corrupted.

Comment: Oh, yeah, `:` in filenames.

Comment: @Fox Well, actually I am extracting it under windows 10 linux subsystem...

Comment: @Fox I have extracted many tar.gz under win10 linux subsystem, never encountered this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely the disk you are extracting to is formatted FAT*.  The FAT* filesystems do not allow `:` to appear in directory entries (filenames).  In order to extract these files, you will need to extract to a different disk or partition whose filesystem *does* support such filenames — common ones include:

- btrfs
- ext3
- ext4
- FFS
- HFS Plus (but not plain HFS)
- NTFS
- XFS