# Why can't I open Tar.gz archive with colons or commas in filename?

Tags: tar, nautilus, zorin

I have a 4Gb tar.gz archive downloaded from a Linux server machine. The machine we are on is a Zorin 16 OS machine. I am using both Nautilus / Archiver (file-roller I think it is) / Xarchiver

We have many files in a sub folder but we can't extract them because Archiver states `Invalid file name`. For example, the names in the archive are:

```
1601142280.M258953P10421.basic.address.com,S=17488,W=19679:2,S
```

I am also unable to rename the files in the archive (renaming to remove the `:` and similar characters).

I need to extract all of these files from the archive into the file system here but I can't do this. How can I get this extraction to work? The file names are not necessarily needing to be preserved.

The `.tar.gz` archive has been downloaded locally on to an `ext4` / USB type data drive.

For each file of this filename structure, using Xachiver extraction GUI returns:

```
/directory/structure/to/files/cur/1699067526.M500170P14222.basic.address.com,S=103498,W=106677\:2,af: Cannot open: Invalid argument
```

And using the `tar xvzf my_archive.tar.gz` format returns:

```
46725.M936P5193.basic.address.com,S=15058,W=15294\:2,Scf: Cannot open: Invalid argument
```

Other files from the archive extract ok.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not sure, it uses a program called "archiver" which I've read elsewhere is a reference to the program "file-roller". THe file is `filename.tar.gz` . The file is openable and readable but I can't extract or edit the files themselves.

Comment: What errors do you get if you open a terminal, `cd` to the directory where the archive is and then run `tar xvzf filename.tar.gz`?

Comment: @terdon `46725.M936P5193.basic.address.com,S=15058,W=15294\:2,Scf: Cannot open: Invalid argument` for all of these types of files

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and add the exact command you ran and at least some of the exact errors so we can see if we can reproduce it (most of us here live in the command line, not the GUI, so the commands really help).

Comment: @terdon I've updated my question with the new details. Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn’t happen to be extracting to an NTFS or CIFS volume, would you?

Comment: @StephenKitt I checked this with GParted and that says the drive is `ext4`  rather than NTFS.

Comment: @Martin Can you confirm the filesystem of your `USB drive` is indeed `ext4` by running `df -hT` or `lsblk -f`. Did you try extracting the `tar` archive to a directory somewhere in `$HOME/`. The error seems to be due to the filesystem of your `USB drive`[1]. Try `tar -xf <your tar archive> -C ~/Downloads/`. [1]https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349914/what-is-tar-error-message-cannot-open-invalid-argument/349915#349915

Comment: @davidt930 GParted states it's ext4.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by booting into Windows 11 and opening the `.tar.gz` file and extracting the containing folder full of the files into the desktop (as a folder) and then running a [PowerShell regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382638/how-can-i-bulk-rename-files-in-powershell) which removed all `,` and `:` from the filenames. Then moving these files back to the USB .

Then the files worked absolutely fine in all aspects on Zorin 16 (Ubuntu).

Maybe there was an issue with the USB filesystem not being the correct type, or perhaps the issue was the tarball was on the USB rather than the `$HOME/` area. But either way; it worked perfectly once the `:` and/or `,` characters were removed.